# SimpleWeather jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm playing with the SimpleWeather jquery plugin, on an asp.net page and its working fine.
https://github.com/monkeecreate/jquery.simpleWeather

I just have 2 questions:

1. I get the times in AM and PM, is there someone thats know how to fix it to 24H.
2. If i know the weather.code http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/#codes can I then somehow us my own names for hot, hail, and so on?

   $.getJSON(
   weatherUrl,
   function (data) {
   if (data !== null && data.query.results !== null) {
       $.each(data.query.results, function (i, result) {
           if (result.constructor.toString().indexOf("Array") !== -1) {
               result = result[0];
           }

   ```
       var currentDate = new Date();
       var sunRise = new Date(currentDate.toDateString() + ' ' + result.astronomy.sunrise);
       var sunSet = new Date(currentDate.toDateString() + ' ' + result.astronomy.sunset);

       if (currentDate > sunRise && currentDate < sunSet) {
           var timeOfDay = 'd';
       } else {
           var timeOfDay = 'n';
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u need to show 24H time with the SimpleWeather jQuery plugin, then the solution from Yuriy is not working...

But here is a working solution.

In the js script find this code.

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var sunRise = new Date(currentDate.toDateString() + ' ' + result.astronomy.sunrise);
var sunSet = new Date(currentDate.toDateString() + ' ' + result.astronomy.sunset);

if (currentDate > sunRise && currentDate < sunSet) {
    var timeOfDay = 'd';
} else {
    var timeOfDay = 'n';
}
```

And then changes that code to this (there is some issue with the sunset in 24H if the sunset is 20:05 then it showed the time as 20:5 i dident show the xx:0x first 0 in the MM-time, this code is fixing that issue)

```
                        var currentDate = new Date();
                        var sunRise = new Date(currentDate.toDateString() + ' ' + result.astronomy.sunrise);
                        var sunSet = new Date(currentDate.toDateString() + ' ' + result.astronomy.sunset);

                        var sunRiseHour = "" + sunRise.getHours() + "";
                        var sunRiseMinute = "" + sunRise.getMinutes() + "";
                        var sunSetHour = "" + sunSet.getHours() + "";
                        var sunSetMinute = "" + sunSet.getMinutes() + "";

                        if (sunRiseHour.length == 1) {
                            sunRiseHour = "0" + sunRiseHour;
                        }
                        if (sunRiseMinute.length == 1) {
                            sunRiseMinute = "0" + sunRiseMinute;
                        }
                        if (sunSetHour.length == 1) {
                            sunSetHour = "0" + sunSetHour;
                        }
                        if (sunSetMinute.length == 1) {
                            sunSetMinute = "0" + sunSetMinute;
                        }
                        var sunRiseTime = sunRiseHour + ":" + sunRiseMinute;
                        var sunSetTime = sunSetHour + ":" + sunSetMinute;


                        if (currentDate > sunRise && currentDate < sunSet) {
                            var timeOfDay = 'd';
                        } else {
                            var timeOfDay = 'n';
                        }
```

Remember to use SunSetTime and SunRiseTime if showing 24H and not the AM/PM ex. SunSet and SunRise.

And it also fix the issue for the HH-time if there is an issue with the first 0 in hours also.
Happy using...

Answer (score 1):

You need to tweak plugin. To enable custom condition text you may add new options property to map condition codes to custom text and use it in plugin as below:

```
// this code is a part of weater object initialization
currently: options.conditions && options.conditions[result.item.condition.code] ? options.conditions[result.item.condition.code] : result.item.condition.text,
high: result.item.forecast[0].high,
low: result.item.forecast[0].low,
forecast: options.conditions && options.conditions[result.item.forecast[0].code] ? options.conditions[result.item.forecast[0].code] : result.item.forecast[0].text,
```

and pass custom property to plugin:

```
$.simpleWeather({
    location: 'Copenhagen, Denmark',
    unit: 'c',
    conditions: { 26: 'Overskyet', 27: 'Mest skyet', 28: 'Mest skyet', 36: 'Hagl' },
```

To change sunrise and sunset time format you also can tweak plugin. This time you need to parse time in `h:mm tt` format and display it in `HH:mm` format instead. If you have `ScriptManager` control on your page you may use Microsoft Ajax Date object extensions functions:

changed plugin's code:

```
$.getJSON(
    weatherUrl,
    function (data) {
        if (data !== null && data.query.results !== null) {
            $.each(data.query.results, function (i, result) {
                if (result.constructor.toString().indexOf("Array") !== -1) {
                    result = result[0];
                }

                var currentDate = new Date();
                if (Date.parseInvariant) {
                    result.astronomy.sunrise = Date.parseInvariant(result.astronomy.sunrise, "h:mm tt").format("HH:mm");
                    result.astronomy.sunset = Date.parseInvariant(result.astronomy.sunset, "h:mm tt").format("HH:mm");
                }
```

Comment: Hi Thx for reply, what a lovely way to help, i got the 2 first codes, and its working 100%, the last code im "blank" how much of the normal JS code, do i need to changes !!?  plz. see edit in main question..

Comment: is there a way to get the UV index.

Comment: Hi Yuriy Rozhovetskiy Have u seen my feedback !?

Comment: Yeah, I seen, but didn't catch you. Could you explain what do you want to achieve. P.S. don't shout at me please

Comment: Hi Yuriy, I will not shout at u at all, why do that to someone thats helping ;)...what do i want to achieve.. my problem is right now that if i changes the code for the §GetJson, with the code u gave me, then its not working, so how much of the code do i need to changes !? im not a pro, so i dont know it, hope u can help me, what i will achieve is to convert between an am/pm time to 24 hour. the other first two code u gave me is working 100% thx for that.

Comment: Place ScriptManager control onto a page and use code from my answer

Comment: i have tryed that, with no luck, what about the IF.......TimeOfDay "d".....TimeOfDay "n"..... do i replace that to with ur code !?